# Http Post request when application is in background

Tags: ios, http, apple-push-notifications, http-post

I have and application which send data usage to the server when a push notification is send to it. But when the application is in background data usage is not send to the server. 
'content-available' = '1' fetch the data usage when in background but not able to HTTP post the data to the server.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Have you had a look at [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html)?

Comment: Obj-C or Swift?

Comment: Objective C @SoundShock